# Ubuntu Server. Issue with full disk

Tags: ubuntu, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ubuntu server slowly filling up](https://serverfault.com/questions/151843/ubuntu-server-slowly-filling-up)
>   [100% disk full on Centos?](https://serverfault.com/questions/164413/100-disk-full-on-centos)

I'm managing web service by using Apache,PHP,MySQL on Ubuntu Server.20 web sites are running.

Almost once a day, Server does not work properly because of being full of root(/) partition. I deleted apache error log because it increased. However, that  didn't solve the problem.

When I reboot the server, it works well again. What should I do now? Please help me.

Capacity of root(/) partition is 20GB, home partition is 437GB.

Comment: Why is the disk filling up?

Comment: Probably any log or cached files, you should identify which files are being created during server uptime

Comment: just type into the shell **find /root -type f -ctime n** (where n stands for n*24 hours ago, so if you want to find files created 1 day ago the value is 1) , identify which files are created during server uptime in the /root partition.

Comment: @0wn3r Also add `-xdev` to restrict the search to the single filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

You obviously have not enough space on your root partition. Some methods to alleviate this problem:

- Check your logrotate settings, maybe you keep to many log files.
- Check your log details settings on the various services that write log files. Some just log too much.
- Move the log files (`/var/log`) to another partition with more space.
- Check what else is using up space. MySQL perhaps? Can you move this?
- Repartition your disk to give root more space (can be quite difficult).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: find out where your space is being eaten up.

```
find / -type d | xargs du -s | sort -g
```

Long answer: put your /var directory on a separate, isolated partition so that your system doesn't crash when this happens, if it is (indeed) a log problem.

Answer (score 1):

do you have graphical interface on the server ? if yes just use this tool: http://gdmap.sourceforge.net/
is just crazy ! :) you can easily find what's consuming so much space.

[image: screenshot of gdmap]

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ncdu` utility](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) to provide a text-based drill-down tree of the filesystem. This will help you identify the directories containing the bulk of your data.

Answer (score 0):

In the same vain as [@Buda Florin's](https://serverfault.com/users/104593/buda-florin) post about [gdmap](https://serverfault.com/a/463462/2518) there is also [fsview](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/fsview.1.html). It's a KDE addon to Konqueror but runs just fine standalone on GNOME. Check out this [blog post](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/5845/command-line-tools-for-analyzing-disk-usage-on-fedoracentosrhel/) for more info on it.

#### Here are some screenshots of fsview in action

[image: fsview #1]
   [image: fsview #2]
   [image: fsview #3]